# Can I combine Reckless Abandon with Debilitating Dichotomy?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Can I combine Reckless Abandon with Debilitating Dichotomy?

Reckless abandon -> cast spell -> roll will -> get success no matter what -> get 1 result better due to spell = crit

> #### Reckless Abandon (Goblin)
>
> **Frequency:** once per day
>
> Despite a lifetime filled with questionable decisions, you've managed to survive, as though you have uncanny luck that lets you avoid the consequences of your own actions. **For the remainder of your turn, if you roll a failure or critical failure on a saving throw against a harmful effect, you get a success instead.** Further, enemies and hazards that would damage you this turn roll the minimum possible damage.
>
> **These benefits apply only to harmful effects incurred entirely during your turn in which you activate Reckless Abandon, such as running through a prismatic wall.** Persistent damage and conditions that were applied prior to your turn proceed normally, and as soon as your turn ends you are subject to the full consequences of any dangers still threatening you.
>
> — *Advanced Player's Guide*, p. 45

> #### Debilitating Dichotomy
>
> **Range** 30 feet; **Targets** 1 creature other than you
>
> **Save** Will
>
> You reveal a glimpse of the impossible conflicts between the divine anathema behind your curse, forcing you to reckon with another's conflicts as well. **You and the target each take 9d6 mental damage with a basic Will save, and the target is stunned 1 if it critically fails its save. You get a degree of success one better than you rolled for your saving throw.**
>
> — *Advanced Player's Guide*, p. 231

Comment: Hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and eventually visit the [help] for some guidance for posting Q&As here! You should specify the game system, adding the proper tag, because there may be several games with mechanics/spells/monsters/etc with the same name but with different mechanics.

Comment: Since the texts of these exactly matches those from PF-2e I've tagged it as such. If you aren't playing that system, please edit the question to clarify. I'd also really see the logic expanded from the simple arrow chain to an actual explanation, so that your thinking becomes clearer.

Answer (score 7):

### Both Depend on the Roll

> For the remainder of your turn, **if you roll a failure or critical failure** on a saving throw against a harmful effect, you get a success instead.

> You get a degree of success one better **than you rolled** for your saving throw.

If you roll a failure on the save for *debilitating dichotomy* while under the effects of Reckless Abandon they would both get you a success instead. Neither changes what you rolled away from a failure, so they don't stack to get you a critical success.

This parallels an update in wording for abilities like Greater Juggernaut described in the [Core Rulebook errata](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq):

> **Changes to the Greater Juggernaut, Greater Resolve, Improved Evasion, and Third Path to Perfection class features**
>
> All three of these abilities grant a two-tier benefit on a failed saving throw of the specified type, but (as always) no ability will ever change your degree of success by more than one step. To clarify, we’re making the following clarification to all three abilities. Change the beginning of the last sentence from “When you fail” a given saving throw to “When you roll a failure on” a giving saving throw.

Comment: I'd change your header to be something along the lines of the abilities not stacking and add a line at the start that they go off what you rolled, not your current level of success. As it stands, until you get to the context of your answer, it sounds like you're saying maybe instead of no